# Slider via uploaded Image on each node + Fallback

Tags: views, entities, nodes, javascript

I want to create a slider block shown on every page filled with the images uploaded to the active Basic Page, Article, ...
On these pages just the Uploaded Images of the active page should be shown and if there are no images uploaded (e.g. on View pages, Taxonomy pages, ...)
a fallback Slider should be shown.

I've added a Imagefield called Sliderimage to the Basic Page (and the others), created some pages and uploaded individual images to them.

Then I've created a view block with the following settings:
Format: Slideshow (default values from views_slideshow)
Show: Fields
Field: Content:Sliderimage - Rendered File, Original, Display all values in the same row (no seperator)
Filter Criteria: Published
Contextual filter: Content: Nid

But somehow the node id seems not to be delivered to the filters (or I misunderstood it) because
at the contextual filter I choose "Display all results for the specified field" at WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE I get all at the different 
pages and with "Hide view" I get nothing would would be right.

If the above issue is solved I want to add  the fallback at "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" as fixed value or php code. 
Would that be the right way?

Comment: Forget about the fallback, that's what I already found out.

Comment: If I define a Fallback, I'll get the fallback on every page even the ones with uploaded images!

Comment: Didn't know that blocks are not able to get the Node-Ids by default, sorry

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to the question title; if you've solved the issue, please answer your own question with the details. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I wanted to answer my questions but the system told me that I'm not able because of the 8hours rule.

Comment: Ah yes, that little treat I forgot about that. If you have a chance in 5 or so hours it'd be great to add the answer in :)

Comment: Yeah, will to that of course if I don't forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved because I've found out that block views don't retrieve node-ids by default.

You have to set at "When the filter value is NOT available":
- Provide default value: with type "Content ID from URL"

Now the block view recognizes the ID as well.